# "Event loop is closed" in Flask/LangChain/asyncio app

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio, langchain

**Context.** I want to run a few LLM requests in parallel. I'm using Flask, LangChain, and asyncio. Flask is installed with the "async" extra.

**Problem.** Every second (!) time the app handles a request, I get the following note in the terminal, repeated as many times as there are items in the analyses list:

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-44' coro=<AsyncClient.aclose() done, defined at [path]\flask-server\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py:2011> exception=RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')>
[Traceback without references to application files]
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

The issue doesn't seem to be critical, as the app just goes on to send a response as expected.

**Questions**: How can I prevent the Runtime Errors? Also, what happening here? Which event loops are getting closed at which point, and why is that a problem?

**Code**

```
# logic
import asyncio

async def run_analyses(analyses):
    tasks = []
    for analysis in analyses:
        task = asyncio.create_task(run_analysis(analysis))
        tasks.append(task)
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results

async def run_analysis(analysis):
    messages = ...
    llm = ChatAnthropic(...)
    response = await llm.ainvoke(messages)
    result = response.content
    return result

# app.py using Flask
import asyncio

@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
async def process():
    data = request.json
    analyses = data['analyses']
    results = await run_analyses(analyses)
    return jsonify(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

**Things I tried**

- await the main app.run
- with and without asyncio.create_task
- 1h of following GPT4's suggestions to no avail :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are those who are dedicated to asgi. I suggest you can try using [Quart](https://pypi.org/project/Quart/).

This one is similar to Flask and is designed as `async` to meet Flask-like requirements and is compatible with flask libraries.